# How to verify arrived object in rx java function with unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing

in my view I have a function which called from presenter with my object, I write a unit test which checks the type of arrived object in that function but how can I check the items in the arrived object(MyModel).

for example, I want to check that the list in my object has 2 items?

**in mock View class**

```
final Action1<MyModel> myAction = mock(Action1.class);

@Override
    public Func1<Observable<MyModel>, Subscription> invalidAppWidgetIdWidgetModal() {
        return RxUi.ui(myAction, Schedulers.immediate());
    }
```

**in test method**

```
verify(mViewMock.myAction()).call(any(MyModel.class));
```

Comment: verify(yourView).methodName(yourobject);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, need to use **ArgumentCaptor**

```
ArgumentCaptor<MyModel> viewModelCapture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyModel.class);
verify(mViewMock. myAction()).call(viewModelCapture.capture());

assertThat(viewModelCapture.getValue().getList‌​Data().size(), is(2));
```